# Wordpress Fetch Sale Price after sales for a WooCommerce product in an API

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I put a sale on one of my orders. The issue is WordPress is not reflecting the sale price in the order detail API of WooCommerce. Also, I looked into the product details but still did not find any sales related data that could help me to find the sale percentage I applied on that product.
These parameters of product detail are null even after the sales.

```
{
    "sale_price": "",
    "date_on_sale_from": null,
    "date_on_sale_from_gmt": null,
    "date_on_sale_to": null,
    "date_on_sale_to_gmt": null
}
```

I am expecting an array of object consisting sale price and date range for that price like

```
{
    'sale_price' : 90,
    'date_started': '2023-10-10',
    'date_ended': '2023-11-10'
}
```